# New HBO Nordic won't play

Tags: flash, pipelight

Am I the only one who can't get HBO Nordic to work after it changed to flash?

The flash player loads and seems fine, but the video never appears.

There are a lot of solutions for the old player, but I can't seem to find anything from after the change (2015).

Edit:

I am using Flash version 17.0.0.134 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

The flash player on HBO reacts exactly the same way on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Many of my HBO using friends have complained about the same :\

Answer (score 7):

Installing the following worked in firefox:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/hal-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libhal1-flash 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

restart firefox.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but only on Firefox, not Chrome.

Comment: No debs for vivid or wily, but it seems to build just fine from source. That means you can replace step 1-2 with `$ bzr branch lp:~mjblenner/+junk/hal-flash`, `autoreconf -i`. `./configure --prefix=/usr` and `sudo make install`.

Answer (score 2):

I followed [the guide in the first post here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274467) and now HBO Nordic plays in Firefox. The plugins did not build at first (maybe I messed up, not closing Firefox or something), but executing the last command of step 5 after a boot did it for me.

**The guide verbatim, all credits to Lubu123 on Ubuntu Forums**:

So here's how to make HBO Nordic work with Firefox - works with Netflix too:

**1. Close Firefox**

**2. Install Pipelight**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

[http://pipelight.net/cms/install/ins...on-ubuntu.html](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html)

**3. As a precaution you may want to get rid of the old flash version** by uninstalling flashplugin-installer (Lubuntu) or adobe-flashplugin (Linux Mint) if you have one installed

```
sudo apt-get remove flashplugin-installer
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin
```

**4. Enable Pipelight's flash and widevine** (you may also want to enable silverlight since although it is not required for HBO, Netflix and many other similar services use it)

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable widevine
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html#section_2

**5. Update plugins and clear Firefox plugin cache like this:**

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

[http://pipelight.net/cms/faqs/faq-pi...utplugins.html](http://pipelight.net/cms/faqs/faq-pipelight-error-in-aboutplugins.html)

**6. Start Firefox and let Pipelight install its plugins** - there will be installation messages on the screen and when they disappear restart Firefox. You should now see the newly installed Pipelight plugins in Firefox plugins tab.